# CSS: Parse Error. Woocommerce plugin <style id='woocommerce-general-inline-css'>

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce, parse-error

I am a beginner with dev and woocommerce, and I have a parse error in woocommerce , the error is about '}' after ';' :

Error: CSS: Parse Error.

At line 84, column 8659

```
inmax(0, 1fr));}}@media (max-w
```

Also, I unminified the code and can't see the error... I am so confuse x) Please I need help to solve this error !

I don't know how to solve the error as it's generated by woocommerce plugin, I have tried to find the file through SSH but can't find it....

This is the  containing the error :

```
<style id='woocommerce-general-inline-css'>
 
#customer_details h3:not(.elementor-widget-woocommerce-checkout-page h3) {
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    padding: 20px 0 14px;
    margin: 0 0 20px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ebebeb;
}

form #order_review_heading:not(.elementor-widget-woocommerce-checkout-page #order_review_heading) {
    border-width: 2px 2px 0 2px;
    border-style: solid;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 1.5em 1.5em 1em;
    border-color: #ebebeb;
}

form #order_review:not(.elementor-widget-woocommerce-checkout-page #order_review) {
    padding: 0 2em;
    border-width: 0 2px 2px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #ebebeb;
}

ul#shipping_method li:not(.elementor-widget-woocommerce-cart #shipping_method li) {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0.25em 0 0.25em 22px;
    text-indent: -22px;
    list-style: none outside;
}

.woocommerce span.onsale,
.wc-block-grid__product .wc-block-grid__product-onsale {
    background-color: #262626;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.woocommerce a.button,
.woocommerce button.button,
.woocommerce .woocommerce-message a.button,
.woocommerce #respond input#submit.alt,
.woocommerce a.button.alt,
.woocommerce button.button.alt,
.woocommerce input.button.alt,
.woocommerce input.button,
.woocommerce input.button:disabled,
.woocommerce input.button:disabled[disabled],
.woocommerce input.button:disabled:hover,
.woocommerce input.button:disabled[disabled]:hover,
.woocommerce #respond input#submit,
.woocommerce button.button.alt.disabled,
.wc-block-grid__products .wc-block-grid__product .wp-block-button__link,
.wc-block-grid__product-onsale {
    color: #ffffff;
    border-color: #666498;
    background-color: #666498;
}

.woocommerce a.button:hover,
.woocommerce button.button:hover,
.woocommerce .woocommerce-message a.button:hover,
.woocommerce #respond input#submit:hover,
.woocommerce #respond input#submit.alt:hover,
.woocommerce a.button.alt:hover,
.woocommerce button.button.alt:hover,
.woocommerce input.button.alt:hover,
.woocommerce input.button:hover,
.woocommerce button.button.alt.disabled:hover,
.wc-block-grid__products .wc-block-grid__product .wp-block-button__link:hover {
    color: #ffffff;
    border-color: rgba(103, 101, 153, 0.81);
    background-color: rgba(103, 101, 153, 0.81);
}

.woocommerce-message,
.woocommerce-info {
    border-top-color: #666498;
}

.woocommerce-message::before,
.woocommerce-info::before {
    color: #666498;
}

.woocommerce ul.products li.product .price,
.woocommerce div.product p.price,
.woocommerce div.product span.price,
.widget_layered_nav_filters ul li.chosen a,
.woocommerce-page ul.products li.product .ast-woo-product-category,
.wc-layered-nav-rating a {
    color: #262626;
}

.woocommerce nav.woocommerce-pagination ul,
.woocommerce nav.woocommerce-pagination ul li {
    border-color: #666498;
}

.woocommerce nav.woocommerce-pagination ul li a:focus,
.woocommerce nav.woocommerce-pagination ul li a:hover,
.woocommerce nav.woocommerce-pagination ul li span.current {
    background: #666498;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.woocommerce-MyAccount-navigation-link.is-active a {
    color: #908ad1;
}

.woocommerce .widget_price_filter .ui-slider .ui-slider-range,
.woocommerce .widget_price_filter .ui-slider .ui-slider-handle {
    background-color: #666498;
}

.woocommerce a.button,
.woocommerce button.button,
.woocommerce .woocommerce-message a.button,
.woocommerce #respond input#submit.alt,
.woocommerce a.button.alt,
.woocommerce button.button.alt,
.woocommerce input.button.alt,
.woocommerce input.button,
.woocommerce-cart table.cart td.actions .button,
.woocommerce form.checkout_coupon .button,
.woocommerce #respond input#submit,
.wc-block-grid__products .wc-block-grid__product .wp-block-button__link {
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-left: 20px;
}

.woocommerce .star-rating,
.woocommerce .comment-form-rating .stars a,
.woocommerce .star-rating::before {
    color: #666498;
}

.woocommerce div.product .woocommerce-tabs ul.tabs li.active:before {
    background: #666498;
}

.woocommerce a.remove:hover {
    color: #666498;
    border-color: #666498;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

.woocommerce[class*="rel-up-columns-"] .site-main div.product .related.products ul.products li.product,
.woocommerce-page .site-main ul.products li.product {
    width: 100%;
}

.woocommerce ul.product-categories>li ul li {
    position: relative;
}

.woocommerce ul.product-categories>li ul li:before {
    content: "";
    border-width: 1px 1px 0 0;
    border-style: solid;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 6px;
    height: 6px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -2px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.woocommerce ul.product-categories>li ul li a {
    margin-left: 15px;
}

@media (min-width:545px) and (max-width:921px) {
    .woocommerce.tablet-columns-3 ul.products li.product,
    .woocommerce-page.tablet-columns-3 ul.products:not(.elementor-grid) {
        grid-template-columns: repeat(3, minmax(0, 1fr));
    }
}

@media (min-width:922px) {
    .woocommerce #reviews #comments {
        width: 55%;
    }
    .woocommerce #reviews #review_form_wrapper {
        width: 45%;
        padding-left: 2em;
    }
    .woocommerce form.checkout_coupon {
        width: 50%;
    }
}

@media (max-width:921px) {
    .ast-header-break-point.ast-woocommerce-cart-menu .header-main-layout-1.ast-mobile-header-stack.ast-no-menu-items .ast-site-header-cart,
    .ast-header-break-point.ast-woocommerce-cart-menu .header-main-layout-3.ast-mobile-header-stack.ast-no-menu-items .ast-site-header-cart {
        padding-right: 0;
        padding-left: 0;
    }
    .ast-header-break-point.ast-woocommerce-cart-menu .header-main-layout-1.ast-mobile-header-stack .main-header-bar {
        text-align: center;
    }
    .ast-header-break-point.ast-woocommerce-cart-menu .header-main-layout-1.ast-mobile-header-stack .ast-site-header-cart,
    .ast-header-break-point.ast-woocommerce-cart-menu .header-main-layout-1.ast-mobile-header-stack .ast-mobile-menu-buttons {
        display: inline-block;
    }
    .ast-header-break-point.ast-woocommerce-cart-menu .header-main-layout-2.ast-mobile-header-inline .site-branding {
        flex: auto;
    }
    .ast-header-break-point.ast-woocommerce-cart-menu .header-main-layout-3.ast-mobile-header-stack .site-branding {
        flex: 0 0 100%;
    }
    .ast-header-break-point.ast-woocommerce-cart-menu .header-main-layout-3.ast-mobile-header-stack .main-header-container {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
    }
    .woocommerce-cart .woocommerce-shipping-calculator .button {
        width: 100%;
    }
    .woocommerce div.product div.images,
    .woocommerce div.product div.summary,
    .woocommerce #content div.product div.images,
    .woocommerce #content div.product div.summary,
    .woocommerce-page div.product div.images,
    .woocommerce-page div.product div.summary,
    .woocommerce-page #content div.product div.images,
    .woocommerce-page #content div.product div.summary {
        float: none;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .woocommerce-cart table.cart td.actions .ast-return-to-shop {
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
        margin-top: 1em;
    }
    .ast-container .woocommerce ul.products:not(.elementor-grid),
    .woocommerce-page ul.products:not(.elementor-grid),
    .woocommerce.tablet-columns-3 ul.products:not(.elementor-grid) {
        grid-template-columns: repeat(3, minmax(0, 1fr));
    }
}

@media (max-width:544px) {
    .ast-separate-container .ast-woocommerce-container {
        padding: .54em 1em 1.33333em;
    }
    .woocommerce-message,
    .woocommerce-error,
    .woocommerce-info {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
    .woocommerce-message a.button,
    .woocommerce-error a.button,
    .woocommerce-info a.button {
        order: 1;
        margin-top: .5em;
    }
    .woocommerce .woocommerce-ordering,
    .woocommerce-page .woocommerce-ordering {
        float: none;
        margin-bottom: 2em;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .woocommerce ul.products a.button,
    .woocommerce-page ul.products a.button {
        padding: 0.5em 0.75em;
    }
    .woocommerce table.cart td.actions .button,
    .woocommerce #content table.cart td.actions .button,
    .woocommerce-page table.cart td.actions .button,
    .woocommerce-page #content table.cart td.actions .button {
        padding-left: 1em;
        padding-right: 1em;
    }
    .woocommerce #content table.cart .button,
    .woocommerce-page #content table.cart .button {
        width: 100%;
    }
    .woocommerce #content table.cart .product-thumbnail,
    .woocommerce-page #content table.cart .product-thumbnail {
        display: block;
        text-align: center !important;
    }
    .woocommerce #content table.cart .product-thumbnail::before,
    .woocommerce-page #content table.cart .product-thumbnail::before {
        display: none;
    }
    .woocommerce #content table.cart td.actions .coupon,
    .woocommerce-page #content table.cart td.actions .coupon {
        float: none;
    }
    .woocommerce #content table.cart td.actions .coupon .button,
    .woocommerce-page #content table.cart td.actions .coupon .button {
        flex: 1;
    }
    .woocommerce #content div.product .woocommerce-tabs ul.tabs li a,
    .woocommerce-page #content div.product .woocommerce-tabs ul.tabs li a {
        display: block;
    }
    .ast-container .woocommerce ul.products:not(.elementor-grid),
    .woocommerce-page ul.products:not(.elementor-grid),
    .woocommerce.mobile-columns-2 ul.products:not(.elementor-grid),
    .woocommerce-page.mobile-columns-2 ul.products:not(.elementor-grid) {
        grid-template-columns: repeat(2, minmax(0, 1fr));
    }
    .woocommerce.mobile-rel-up-columns-2 ul.products::not(.elementor-grid) {
        grid-template-columns: repeat(2, minmax(0, 1fr));
    }
}

@media (max-width:544px) {
    .woocommerce ul.products a.button.loading::after,
    .woocommerce-page ul.products a.button.loading::after {
        display: inline-block;
        margin-left: 5px;
        position: initial;
    }
    .woocommerce.mobile-columns-1 .site-main ul.products li.product:nth-child(n),
    .woocommerce-page.mobile-columns-1 .site-main ul.products li.product:nth-child(n) {
        margin-right: 0;
    }
    .woocommerce #content div.product .woocommerce-tabs ul.tabs li,
    .woocommerce-page #content div.product .woocommerce-tabs ul.tabs li {
        display: block;
        margin-right: 0;
    }
}

@media (min-width:922px) {
    .woocommerce #content .ast-woocommerce-container div.product div.images,
    .woocommerce .ast-woocommerce-container div.product div.images,
    .woocommerce-page #content .ast-woocommerce-container div.product div.images,
    .woocommerce-page .ast-woocommerce-container div.product div.images {
        width: 50%;
    }
    .woocommerce #content .ast-woocommerce-container div.product div.summary,
    .woocommerce .ast-woocommerce-container div.product div.summary,
    .woocommerce-page #content .ast-woocommerce-container div.product div.summary,
    .woocommerce-page .ast-woocommerce-container div.product div.summary {
        width: 46%;
    }
    .woocommerce.woocommerce-checkout form #customer_details.col2-set .col-1,
    .woocommerce.woocommerce-checkout form #customer_details.col2-set .col-2,
    .woocommerce-page.woocommerce-checkout form #customer_details.col2-set .col-1,
    .woocommerce-page.woocommerce-checkout form #customer_details.col2-set .col-2 {
        float: none;
        width: auto;
    }
}

.woocommerce a.button,
.woocommerce button.button.alt,
.woocommerce-page table.cart td.actions .button,
.woocommerce-page #content table.cart td.actions .button,
.woocommerce a.button.alt,
.woocommerce .woocommerce-message a.button,
.ast-site-header-cart .widget_shopping_cart .buttons .button.checkout,
.woocommerce button.button.alt.disabled,
.wc-block-grid__products .wc-block-grid__product .wp-block-button__link {
    border: solid;
    border-top-width: 0;
    border-right-width: 0;
    border-left-width: 0;
    border-bottom-width: 0;
    border-color: #666498;
}

.woocommerce a.button:hover,
.woocommerce button.button.alt:hover,
.woocommerce-page table.cart td.actions .button:hover,
.woocommerce-page #content table.cart td.actions .button:hover,
.woocommerce a.button.alt:hover,
.woocommerce .woocommerce-message a.button:hover,
.ast-site-header-cart .widget_shopping_cart .buttons .button.checkout:hover,
.woocommerce button.button.alt.disabled:hover,
.wc-block-grid__products .wc-block-grid__product .wp-block-button__link:hover {
    border-color: rgba(103, 101, 153, 0.81);
}

.widget_product_search button {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    ;
}

@media (min-width:922px) {
    .woocommerce.woocommerce-checkout form #customer_details.col2-set,
    .woocommerce-page.woocommerce-checkout form #customer_details.col2-set {
        width: 55%;
        float: left;
        margin-right: 4.347826087%;
    }
    .woocommerce.woocommerce-checkout form #order_review,
    .woocommerce.woocommerce-checkout form #order_review_heading,
    .woocommerce-page.woocommerce-checkout form #order_review,
    .woocommerce-page.woocommerce-checkout form #order_review_heading {
        width: 40%;
        float: right;
        margin-right: 0;
        clear: right;
    }
}


</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue. for more details you can refer to this link :
https://github.com/CSSLint/csslint/issues/753

Comment: I am so sorry but not sure to understand how to solve my problem on wordpress :/